# Datatables retorna varios datos

Tags: datatables, consola, click, mensajes

tengo una tabla creada con datatables, ahi tengo un boton para que me muestre los datos por consola, este codigo me muestra los datos

este es el codigo html de la tabla

```
<table id="dt_datos" class="display supertable table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer dtr-inline table-striped table-hover" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Almacen</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>SKU</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio Unitario</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Proveedor</th>
                <th>Contacto</th>
                <th>Creado Por</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
           </table>
```

llamo creo el datatables con ajax y llamada a la funcion

```
function mostrar_tabla_productos_bajo_stock_por_proveedor(id_proveedor,id_almacen){
var dt_datos=$('#dt_datos').DataTable({
    "ajax":{
        "method":'POST',
        'data':{'accion':'llenar_tabla_productos_bajo_stock_por_proveedor','id_proveedor':id_proveedor,'id_almacen':id_almacen},
        'url':'accion.php',
    },
    "columns":[
        {"defaultContent":""},
        {"data":"nombre_almacen"},
        {"data":"nombre"},
        {"data":"sku"},
        {"data":"stock"},
        {"data":"stock_min"},
        {"data":"stock_max"},
        {"defaultContent":""},
        {"defaultContent":""},
        {"defaultContent":""},
        {"data":"estado"},
        {"defaultContent":""},
        {"defaultContent":'<a type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs mostrar">Cotizar</a>'}
    ]
 });

 obtener_data_mostrar('#dt_datos',dt_datos);
```

}

esta es la funcion

```
function obtener_data_mostrar(tbody,table){
    $(tbody).on("click",'a.mostrar',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data=table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        console.log(data 
    });
}
```

y me muestra esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al hacer clic en un solo boton, como pueden ver me muestra datos diferentes, podrian darme alguna solucion para evitar esto

Comment: Deberias de mostrar mas codigo.

Comment: ya agregue el codigo de la funcion

Comment: Agrega tambien el HTML.

Comment: ya agregue el html y el codigo de como creo el datatable

Comment: Puedes utilizar el parent(), sin la s porque parents() te va a traer todos los rows y parent solo 1, tal vez por eso te muestra todas las filas

Comment: lo intente y me muestra este error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'idproducto_almacen' of undefined

Comment: Tu tabla se llama `dt_detalle_cotizacion` pero creas el datatable con `dt_datos?

Comment: si, olvide cambiarlo aqui, pero se llama dt_datos, ya corregi la pregunta

Comment: Pues a mi me funciona bien tu codigo.

Comment: no tengo idea porque me arroja datos distintos por consola, pero me arroja varios datos como se ve en la imagen